# Write file to sdcard in android

Tags: android, file, android-sdcard

I want to create a file on sdcard. Here I can create file and read/write it to the application, but what I want here is, the file should be saved on specific folder of sdcard. How can I do that using `FileOutputStream`?

```
// create file
    public void createfile(String name) 
    {
        try
        {
            new FileOutputStream(filename, true).close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // write to file

    public void appendToFile(String dataAppend, String nameOfFile) throws IOException 
    {
        fosAppend = openFileOutput(nameOfFile, Context.MODE_APPEND);
        fosAppend.write(dataAppend.getBytes());
        fosAppend.write(System.getProperty("line.separator").getBytes());
        fosAppend.flush();
        fosAppend.close();
    }
```

Comment: check the docs. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html. are you trying to store in internal storage?

Comment: yes, I want to store file in internal storage...

Comment: then your question title needs to be changed Write file to internal storage in android

Comment: sorry, mybad... I want to store on sdcard...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try like this,

```
try {
    File newFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "TestFolder");
    if (!newFolder.exists()) {
        newFolder.mkdir();
    }
    try {
        File file = new File(newFolder, "MyTest" + ".txt");
        file.createNewFile();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("ex: " + ex);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("e: " + e);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Here's an example from my code:

```
try {
    String filename = "abc.txt";
    File myFile = new File(Environment
            .getExternalStorageDirectory(), filename);
    if (!myFile.exists())
        myFile.createNewFile();
    FileOutputStream fos;
    byte[] data = string.getBytes();
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
        fos.write(data);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And don't forget the:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty easy to create folder and write file on sd card in android

**Code snippet**

```
    String ext_storage_state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
            File mediaStorage = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + "/Folder name");
            if (ext_storage_state.equalsIgnoreCase(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
                if (!mediaStorage.exists()) {
                    mediaStorage.mkdirs();
                } 
                //write file writing code..

try {

                FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(file name);
                try {
                    fos.write(filename.toByteArray());
                    fos.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }           
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            }
            else
            {
                //Toast message sd card not found..
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: 'getExternalStorageDirectory()' 
actually gives you a path to /storage/emulated/0 and not the actual sdcard

'String path = Syst.envr("SECONDARY_STORAGE");' gives you a path to the sd card