# Why my `ExifInterfae` is not showing properties?

Tags: android

I have the following code:

```
YuvImage yuv = new YuvImage(result.getExtractImageData(), 
        camera.getParameters().getPreviewFormat(),
        result.getWidth(), 
        result.getHeight(), null);

ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
yuv.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0, 0, result.getWidth(), result.getHeight()), 100, out);

byte[] bytes = out.toByteArray();

Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);

image = RotateImage(image, rotation);

createDirectoryAndSaveFile(image, "Image_" + result.getCaptureTime() + ".jpg");

String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/MyFolder/Image_" + result.getCaptureTime() + ".jpg";
try {
    ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(filePath);
    exif.getAttribute("UserComment");

    // call this next setAttributes a few times to write all the GPS data to it.
    exif.setAttribute("UserComment", String.valueOf(result.getCaptureTime()));
    exif.saveAttributes();
} 
catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

It is supposed to punt under `UserComment` the `result.getCaptureTime()` at which it was captured from the camera. I download it to a Windows folder and I can't see the properties I just created...

What I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

```
private void createDirectoryAndSaveFile(Bitmap imageToSave, String fileName)           
{
        File direct = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/MyFolder");

        if (!direct.exists()) {
            File wallpaperDirectory = new File("/sdcard/MyFolder/");
            wallpaperDirectory.mkdirs();
        }

        File file = new File(new File("/sdcard/MyFolder/"), fileName);
        if (file.exists()) {
            file.delete();
        }
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            imageToSave.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: To begin with: What is 'result'?

Comment: 'createDirectoryAndSaveFile(image, "Image_" + result.getCaptureTime() + ".jpg");' Well you are saving a bitmap 'image' to file. Where is the code? Are you saving a bitmap or do you convert to .jpg?

Comment: 'catch (IOException e) '. Do you have a catch? How do you know?

Comment: Hard to explain what's `result`... It contains information about the recently captured image. I forgot to post the `createDirectoryAndSaveFile`. Sorry...

Comment: I have a catch, but it never happens (I debugged, of course...)

Comment: Your newly added function works with three paths and the final path does not match with the one you use later. A mess.

Comment: I made a mistake with folder name. Don't be ofensive, please. I'm always respectful.

Comment: That code comes from here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20369870/760893

Comment: 'exif.saveAttributes()'. Does that really save to file? Please tell what the file length is before and after this statement. By the way: Why are you reading exif info from that file? There will not be any exif info in your newly created file.

Comment: That's what I don't know and I haven't read that anywhere. I just want to add ExifInfo to my image... The debug doesn't break there, that's why I suppose it's being saved.

Comment: With all my respect too: I see `MyFolder`  everywhere...  For me that part is working, and my main question is not that, my main question is: `how to add  exif info to my image`, but no answer. So now that I see that this thread is being ignored because so much unhelpful comments, only critiques, I will close it. Thank you.